# Adding mutex onto OpenCL kernel

Tags: opencl, mutex

I have the following OpenCL code defining a kernel function:

```
kernel void test_print(global char* src)
{
    printf("%c\t", src[0]);
    src[0]++;
    printf("%c\n", src[0]);
}
```

the `src` is an array with one element `{'0'};`

The output is

```
0   0   0   0   1
1
1
1
```

I reckon this is caused by that there is no mutex for each thread. But how to add mutex in OpenCL? Could someone give any simple examples?

Comment: There is no way to add mutex in OpenCL. In SIMD all threads need to process at the same time each instruction. Blocking one thread, blocks the entire group of threads. There are workarounds using global/local memory + atomics, but are horribly slow so I prefer not to encourage people to use them.

Answer (score 1):

```
__kernel void test_print(__global char* src, __global int* increment)
{
    printf("%c\t", src[0]);
    if(atomic_add(increment, 1)==get_global_id(0))
    {
        src[0]++;
    }
    printf("%c\n", src[0]);
}
```

This should work with a 1D problem but in effect, it is horribly slow. It could be improved by means of using barriers inside blocks instead of using an atomic operation for each thread. Nevertheless, I would recomend you to reconsider the possibility to split your work in several kernels, trying to avoid these atomic operations.